# What is the best way to reencode a video with Xvid?

Tags: video, encoding, xvid, bitrate

What is the best way to reencode a video with Xvid? I used FFmpeg in the past (I havent tried using FFmpeg with Xvid however - does FFmpeg keep up with Xvid releases?).

With FFmpeg I either need to figure out the bitrate of the video then reencode it slightly below or I use -sameq (I think it's same quality), however - that produces a file thats bigger and not better then a slightly less bitrate file.

Whats a good way to reecode these videos? (By the way - they are all on my HD as FLV1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) does Xvid. Here's a tutorial [how-to](http://www.doom9.org/xvid-vdub-final.htm), if required.

Answer (score 2):

You can give [meGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/) a shot if you're a Windows user.

For the best quality, make sure you're doing two-pass encodes.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for it.  It does not have XviD, but uses the FFmpeg library for MPEG-4 encoding, which offers similar quality:

[image]

ffmpeg is good (even better) if you will learn the [controlling options](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/02/24/ffmpeg-the-ultimate-video-and-audio-manipulation-tool/) and check the [MPEG-4 encoding guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/MPEG-4).

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v mpeg4 -vtag xvid -qscale:v 3 -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 4 output.avi
```

Comment: Can't go past Handbrake. I have lost count of how many times I have recommended it to others here on SU.

Answer (score 1):

[SUPER](http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html) is what I use. Once you've managed find the download link (they've made it especially difficult on their site), installation and use is quite easy.

<sub>To find the download link, follow these steps:</sub>

- click on the link above
- scroll to the bottom and click on the 'Start Downloading SUPER' link
- click on the 'download and use' link
- scroll to the bottom and click on the 'Download SUPER © setup file' link

The strange thing is that you really have to follow this route, otherwise the last link doesn't work. Why they've done it this way goes beyond me.

Comment: +1 Super is simply the best universal converter, never failed me.

Answer (score 0):

It may be just me, but i've had trouble doing 2pass encodes with SUPER.
I know use mencoder for all my encodes. If the command line scares you, you can check out some graphical frontends on doom9.org forums :)